# How to connect a Button to a new Canvas window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm making a simple game with tkinter module in python. I have made some feature that is when user click to `Button` , it'll destroy the `w.canvas` then show the new canvas and `button3`, `4`, `5`. But I have problem when I try to connect `button3` with a new `Canvas` (the main content of my simple game) when user click into the `button3`. The compiler shows the error as `TypeError: onClick1() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`.

Here is all my code:

```
import tkinter as tk, time
from tkinter import messagebox

master = tk.Tk()
master.title('Game wrote by Ta Dang Phong')
w = tk.Canvas(master, width=760, height=570, bg='blue')
w.pack() w.create_rectangle(152, 57, 608, 171, fill="yellow")
w.create_text((380,110),fill='red', font='times 28', text='SIMP GAME ', width=500)
button = tk.Button(master, text='START', font='times 28',width=10 , command=w.destroy)
button1 = tk.Button(master, text='GAF NOOB', font='times 28',width=10 )
button2 = tk.Button(master, text='EXIT', font='times 28',width=10 )

def onClick1():
    sc = tk.Canvas(master,width=760,height=570,bg='yellow')
    sc.pack()

class game:
    def onClick(event):
        global w
        w=tk.Canvas(master, width=760, height=570, bg='green')
        w.pack()
        w.create_rectangle(152,57,608,171,fill='orange')
        w.create_text(380,110,fill='red',font='times 28',text='MODE',width=400)
        button3 = tk.Button(master,text='HARD',font='times 28', width=10)
        button4 = tk.Button(master,text='NORMAL',font='times 28', width=10)
        button5 = tk.Button(master,text='BACK',font='times 28', width=10)
        canvas_widget = w.create_window(375, 238, window=button3)
        canvas_widget = w.create_window(375, 338, window=button4)
        canvas_widget = w.create_window(375, 438, window=button5)
        button3.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', onClick1)

button.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', game.onClick)
canvas_widget = w.create_window(375, 238, window=button)
canvas_widget = w.create_window(375, 338, window=button1)
canvas_widget = w.create_window(375, 438, window=button2)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: A function that is invoked via a `.bind()` call on a widget gets called with one parameter (such as the `event` you have declared for your `onClick()` function) - you have to declare such a parameter even if you don't have any use for it.  But `.bind()` isn't normally how you specify an action for a Button - use the `command=` option when creating it, in which case no parameter gets passed.

Comment: In addition to that, you never create an instance of your `game` class, so `button.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', game.onClick)` will not work.

Comment: Thanks for your answere but my problem is the connect of button3 with onClick1() in line "button3.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', onClick1)"

Comment: You need to add `event` argument to `onClick1()` function definition: `def onClick1(event):`, like that for `game.onClick()` function.